# Wake On LAN (WOL) through router?

Tags: router, home-server, wake-on-lan

I have a home server which has Wake On Lan configured and I am able to wake the server using a simple program on Windows 7. My question is if I have a router with WOL support will this allow me to wake the server from any device or program when they try to access the server?

Example:
A Raspberry Pi with XBMC attempts to access a shared drive on the server to watch a video, will the router then wake the server?

Answer (score 0):

XBMC trying to access a shared drive on it's own won't wake up the server with the shared drive. For Wake On Lan to work, a so called magic packet has to be sent. However there is an Add-on for XBMC that might help you: http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Add-on:Advanced_Wake_On_Lan